# should we always use a EJB to implement a webservice? are there any other ways?

Tags: web-services, ejb-3.0, jax-ws, glassfish-3

I was going through a Jax-ws sample tutorial, my question is why we should use a EJB to implement a webservice? are there any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you put up your *WebService* somehow like this:

```
@WebService
@Stateless
public class Webservice {

  @WebMethod
  public boolean returnTrue() {
    // your stuff here
    return true;
  }
}
```

You don't really need the **@Stateless**-Annotation for your WebService to work and therefore you can waive to *use* EJB functionality in your Project.

There are several ways of implementing WebServices in Java like [JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) or REST ([JAX-RS](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html)).
Additionally you can use supporting implementations like [JAX-B](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html) or [JAX-RPC](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/getstartjaxrpc/).

This is just a fraction of all the possibilities but it should be a good base to get you started.

Hope this helpes, have Fun!

---

**EDIT:**

> my question is why we should use a EJB to implement a webservice?

Sorry, I didn't focused on that the first time.
As said above *you don't need* EJB functionality to make a WebService work but it is most common to do this, because :

- The invokation of a Bean within Java is simple (you can use Dependency Injection or a lookup)
- You don't have to generate your client-stubs for every WebService-class
- You're able to use the whole Java functionality from a Bean while WebServices are restricted. E.g. WebServices only allow sending [simple datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnazc.html) between client and server (though it's possible to send comlpex objects but it's much more difficult)

Hope this could make things more clear. Have Fun!